# Determine response from PHP in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

All,
I've got a function that basically gets triggered when an Upload finishes. I have the following code in that function:

```
onFinish: function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.result);
},
```

When I do this I get the following response in my console:

```
[{
    "name": "1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "size": 35535,
    "type": "image\/jpeg",
    "url": "\/web\/upload\/1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "thumbnail_url": "\/web\/upload\/thumbnails\/1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "delete_url": "\/web\/upload.php?file=1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "delete_type": "DELETE",
    "upload_type": "video_montage"
}]
```

I'd like to get the value that is in the `upload_type` and do some actions based on that but I'm not sure how to get this from my function. Any help would be appreciated to get this information.

Thanks!

Comment: @ColeJohnson: the question is vague, but I'd guess that the response is pre-parsed, since OP didn't wrap the given data in quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.result` is an array, you need to access the first element and then access `upload_type`.

Try `console.log(data.result[0].upload_type);`

***Update:***
 If data.result is a string, you need to parse it first.Try

```
var result = JSON.parse(data.result); 
console.log(result[0].upload_type);
```

Comment: Same result, I still get an undefined in the console

Comment: @user1048676 If `data.result` is a string, you need to parse it first.Try `var result = JSON.parse(data.result); console.log(result[0].upload_type);`

Comment: @user1048676 If this is an AJAX response in jQuery (which the tags seem to indicate), you can save yourself the parsing by setting `dataType: "json"` when issuing the request. Note, too, that `JSON.parse` only works in some modern browsers - unless jQuery patches it in, but I don't think they do. :/

Answer (score 1):

You would access the `upload_type` property by the following:

```
onFinish: function (e, data) {
    var uploadType = data.result[0].upload_type;
},
```

`data.result[x]` specifies to grab the object within the x key of your array.  If you had multiple objects within your array then you would utilize a for loop to iterate each key.

To access the other properties you would follow the same principle.  Based off of the desired action, you will handle the data appropriately.

Edit: What does the following return?

```
var obj = data.result[0];
for(var item in obj){
   console.log(item + ': ' + obj[item]);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yYHmQ/

Comment: Thanks, when I do that I get an undefined even though it still shows in my results.

Comment: Same situation even after that. I still get an undefined message.

Comment: @user1048676 There must be something else going on if its a valid object.  Everything is working as expected in the jsFiddle demo provided above.