# IE gives an error trying to parse JSON

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

All,
I'm trying to parse some JSON and IE is giving me an error but not surprisingly the other browsers are ok with it. Here is my code:

```
var result = JSON.parse(data.result); 
var uploadType = result[0].upload_type;
var filename = result[0].name;
var insert_id = result[0].insert_id;
```

I'm getting an error on the first line. Any idea how to make this IE proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate ['JSON' is undefined error in IE only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093582/json-is-undefined-error-in-ie-only)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support `JSON.parse` before version 8. You may use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON) instead (as I see you have tagged the question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)).

Comment: Thanks, I am using jQuery. Can I just simply replace JSON.parse with jQuery.parseJSON?

Comment: In addition to that, will the jQuery.parseJSON work in my other browsers the same way?

Comment: When I updated it, I get the following error now: Message: '0' is null or not an object

Comment: @user1048676: Could you please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the error?

Comment: JSon is suppoerted in ie8 .

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer doesnt support JSON.parse, reference the [json2](http://www.json.org/js.html) script at and you will get the same functionality.

Comment: When I added the json2 script it gets past the first error but then it tells me that Message: '0' is null or not an object

Comment: Are you sure you are parsing a valid JSON string?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I used this code because of this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406202/determine-response-from-php-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the IE version, but if you're using IE8 or earlier, it doesn't support the JSON object natively.

You'll need a third-party library to polyfill this feature.

jQuery is one option.

You can find a bunch of other options here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: You're correct, it's IE8. I'm also using jQuery. How can I make this snippet work with jQuery?

Comment: the context of your code snippet is unclear, but jquery provides transparent json encoding/decoding for its ajax calling routines. If you're receiving the `result` variable via an ajax call, jquery should be able to provide it already decoded. If the context is not ajax, then you can use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this one and this worked for me:
https://github.com/flowersinthesand/jquery-stringifyJSON

The previous solutions doesn't work for me, even this:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

For those who cannot use third libraries, you can always make use of

```
eval('var data = ' + request.responseText);
```

to get the same functionality

Comment: Be careful about using eval function, because that can inject javascript. Use only if you have full control about the contents. Imagine the "request.responseText" contains some part of a field inserted by some user. The user can fill javascript code to be injected on the page!

Comment: You're right, `eval()` isn't safe at all, but we speak here about IE... :D